# Devise log_in errors not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have been looking at similar questions but I haven't been able to pinpoint my error.

I have this code in my `application.html.erb`, and it works when it comes to showing other flash messages (such as "Successful login"):

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But regardless of that the errors don't display on sign in for any of my models (I have 3 different models).

This is the response of the requests:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-14 16:25:35 -0300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5yM5EkGw1WVrFsaHm39Em7JkXgu0OZb5FDeO7bJA+SEQBYBybfw7ghbK1WM5I8krbBjP/pRWLF+PG0B2k+Crkw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"user0@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Iniciar sesión"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "user0@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 107ms (ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)


Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5yM5EkGw1WVrFsaHm39Em7JkXgu0OZb5FDeO7bJA+SEQBYBybfw7ghbK1WM5I8krbBjP/pRWLF+PG0B2k+Crkw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"user0@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Iniciar sesión"}
  Rendering users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 285ms (Views: 223.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

But flash is empty if user/password is wrong or if user hasn't been confirmed yet.

I have redefined my controllers to get them working correctly for multiple models, as explained in the [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include Accessible
  skip_before_action :check_user, only: :destroy
end
```

But I haven't redefined the methods.

Comment: Looks like you have redefine devise controllers, you should remember to set flash messages in your controllers.

Comment: @kolas I have redefined the controllers to get them working correctly for multiple models https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

Comment: According to this guide you have flash.clear in check_user method, i think thats why no messages after errors

Comment: Try to move ```flash.clear``` inside if statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was tagged with 'devise' so I assume you are using it. Devise errors are not flash messages and not implementing this mechanism. Take a look into this partial `devise_error_messages!`. You could include it inside your Devise form.

#### Update

I am updating my answer following the question updates. I've created a new app with three Devise models as described and used the code snippet from the question to generate the flashes. I've followed the tutorial from the question description and was able to reproduce your issue. It appears that the `flash.clear` in the concern *clears* the flash when user redirects back to the new session view.

You could add the following:

```
flash.clear unless params['action'] == 'new'
```

as a quick hack to prevent the flash clear on redirects back to new session page.

Comment: I read that they use `flash` for login and `devise_error_messages!` for the other actions.

Comment: @moondaisy, you are right. I see that you updated your question since my answer. Can you byebug or print the flash in the view and in the concern before the flash.clear? Also do you see errors on the resource?

Comment: I have byebug the flash in the view and it's empty, I will try in the concern and update soon

Comment: I wasn't seeing the `flash.clear` and spent hours on this! Thanks!